# ¿Como se puede dejar activo un nav-tab asignandole un valor predeterminado?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Aquí llamo al valor que quiero dejar como predeterminada:

```
<?php
session_start();
include ("../../model/database.php");

if(!isset($_SESSION['rol'])){
        header('location: /index.php');
        echo 'Debes estar logeado';
}else{
    if($_SESSION['rol'] !=16){ 
        header('location: /index.php');
        echo 'No estas logeado como Jefe de Wellboat';
    }else{
        $fechaActual = date('Y-m-d');
        $seDistNave = 'CA7455';
    }
}
```

?>

y acá está mi listado al cual quiero asignarle $seDistNave, tengo entendido que se tiene que agregar una clase llamada active, pero mi listado me trae varias tablas dependiendo de las que se encuentran en la base de datos y Ahora no sé como implementar la clase active a mi listado: `
<?php
foreach ($seDistNaveProgramaMensual as $seDistNavePrograma) {

```
                    $query = "SELECT * FROM naves
                    WHERE seDistNave = '$seDistNavePrograma'";
                    $result = $conn->query($query);
                    foreach ($result as $row) {
                        $nave = $row['nombre']; 
                    }
                ?>
                    <li class="nav-item mx-2" id="listadoNaves">
                        <a class="nav-link small" href="#panelNaves<?php echo $seDistNavePrograma?>" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><?php echo $nave?></a>
                    </li>
                <?php } ?>
            </ul> `
```

Comment: para eso hay una clase especifica en css `<a class="nav-link active" href="#">Active</a>`

Comment: hola muy buenas tardes @ArcanisGK507, si, lo he implementado pero como el listado es recorrido con un foreach, activa todas las opciones que esta me trae.

Comment: tienes en algun lugar un parametro guardado que que te diga cual debe ser el tab activo? si no lo tienes eso es lo primero que debes buscar la forma de implementar, luego ese parametro lo usas para evaluar cual tab es el activo. logica basica ...

Comment: no, no lo tenía, muchas gracias @ArcanisGK507 , trataré de implementarlo.